# What is the best design pattern/architecture for my situation

Tags: android, design-patterns, architecture, multiplayer

Firstly, hi everyone.

So I will have an app running on an Android OS - this is what my clients will be using.

I will have a server + database (typical back end backbone) which they all can connect to and retrieve info from - pretty much the repository for storing all data which the clients require in order for their Android app to run.

So basically, can anyone suggest a design pattern/architecture which best suits the following requirement:

(1) A client(A) is associated with a score, a simple int value lets say.(like football league)
     - If the client(A) is given a score from another client(B), client(A) score is updated

(2) A client(A) can add many friends ( clients(C,D,E,...) ) to their league table
     -  client(A) league table and client(A) list of friends will be stored in a local database on client(A) android advice.

(At this point, my view is that client(A) will have to connect to my server + database to retrieve updates (VERY IMPORTANT: The server will never contact them to let them know there is an update))

(3) If one client(A) gives another client(B) a score, it is accrued to the client's(B) score.

(4) Any clients(C,D,E,...) who have client(B) in their league table will need to be updated about this update ONLY WHEN THEY ACCESS THEIR APP AGAIN AND THEY CHECK FOR UPDATES, i.e: I only want the update to take place if the clients(C,D,E,...) connect to the server (as opposed to the *server* attempting to inform the client that their is an update awaiting them)

NOTE: I am not using Google Cloud Messaging btw

Hope that makes sense and thanks in advance for any comments

Comment: Have you done anythings from your end ?

Comment: Hi, I have my server and database setup and the client is connecting  successfully using HTTPURLCONNECTION. The client's database has the friend table setup and backend and client are sending JSON objects of type Friend to one another. TBH, I have done very little as of yet, only design a solution. I wanted to get other peoples advice before I went "gung ho" with my design